# c# asynchronous socket accessed by multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous, thread-safety

I would like to use the C# asynchronous io model for my socket. I have multiple
threads that need to send over the socket. What is the best way of handling this?
A pool of N sockets,with access controlled by lock? Or is asynch send thread-safe
for multiple threads accessing a single socket?

THanks!

Jacko

Comment: http://www.albahari.com/threading/ is handy to read when trying to find the best threading solution.

Comment: Do you have a protocol you need to follow? Do the streams have to be transferred sequential?

Comment: Thanks, Patrick. Albahari does look useful. I am using the socket to set and get values on a remote server. I am looking into asynchronous socket io, but I understand that it uses the system thread pool. So, I

Comment: may have the situation of a SET followed by a GET, and the GET gets processed before the SET, so GET returns older values. This might happen if SET and GET were processed by two different threads, and the second thread was faster than the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The async methods already create new threads to send the data. This will probably add unnecessary overhead to your application. If you already have multiple threads, you can create an IDispoable type of object to represent access to the socket and a manager which will control the checkin and checkout for the socket. The socket would checkin itself when the IDisposable dispose method is called. This way you can control what methods your threads can perform on the socket as well.
If the socket is already checked out by another thread, the manager would simply block until it's available.

```
using (SharedSocket socket = SocketManager.GetSocket())
{
    //do things with socket
}
```

Comment: Thanks, good idea. I do have something like this already. I am just worried that this will not scale well as the calling threads grow. They might spend a lot of time blocking.

Comment: If the threads are only writing to the socket, you can use a queue to put the data to be written in the socket, and have another thread consuming the data. This way the calling threads wouldn't need to block at all.

Comment: Thanks. Will try that out. I also want to make use of multi-core, so I might run a couple of these queued sockets.

Answer (score 1):

`System.Threading.Semaphore` is something that becomes handy in synchronizing and racing conditions